Flink application with statsd failing transiently
We are using "com.datadoghq" % "java-dogstatsd-client" % "4.2.0", as SBT dependency for our Flink application. Suddenly during HPA rescaling or any general redeployment we are seeing the following jnr related error from StatsDClientBuilder
Flink version: 1.18
DatadogClient: 3.33.0
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load FFI provider jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.Provider
    at jnr.ffi.provider.InvalidRuntime.newLoadError(InvalidRuntime.java:101)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.InvalidRuntime.findType(InvalidRuntime.java:42)
    at jnr.ffi.Struct$NumberField.<init>(Struct.java:872)
    at jnr.ffi.Struct$Unsigned16.<init>(Struct.java:1240)
    at jnr.unixsocket.SockAddrUnix$DefaultSockAddrUnix.<init>(SockAddrUnix.java:209)
    at jnr.unixsocket.SockAddrUnix.create(SockAddrUnix.java:174)
    at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketAddress.<init>(UnixSocketAddress.java:53)
    at com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder$1.call(NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder.java:261)
    at com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder$1.call(NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder.java:259)
    at com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder.staticAddressResolution(NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder.java:283)
    at com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder.staticStatsDAddressResolution(NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder.java:299)
    at com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder.resolve(NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder.java:217)
    at com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder.build(NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder.java:193)
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceOperatorStreamTask$AsyncDataOutputToOutput.emitRecord(SourceOperatorStreamTask.java:309)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.source.SourceOutputWithWatermarks.collect(SourceOutputWithWatermarks.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter$SourceOutputWrapper.collect(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema.deserialize(DeserializationSchema.java:84)
org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.deserializer.KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.deserialize(KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.java:51)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not get native definition for type `POINTER`, original error message follows: java.io.IOException: Unable to write jffi binary stub to `/tmp`. Set `TMPDIR` or Java property `java.io.tmpdir` to a read/write path that is not mounted "noexec".
    at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.tempReadonlyError(StubLoader.java:414)
    at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.loadFromJar(StubLoader.java:399)
    at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.load(StubLoader.java:278)
    at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.<clinit>(StubLoader.java:487)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Init.load(Init.java:68)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign$InstanceHolder.getInstanceHolder(Foreign.java:49)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign$InstanceHolder.<clinit>(Foreign.java:45)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign.getInstance(Foreign.java:103)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Type$Builtin.lookupTypeInfo(Type.java:242)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Type$Builtin.getTypeInfo(Type.java:237)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Type.resolveSize(Type.java:155)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Type.size(Type.java:138)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime$TypeDelegate.size(NativeRuntime.java:178)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.AbstractRuntime.<init>(AbstractRuntime.java:48)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.<init>(NativeRuntime.java:57)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.<init>(NativeRuntime.java:41)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime$SingletonHolder.<clinit>(NativeRuntime.java:53)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.getInstance(NativeRuntime.java:49)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.Provider.<init>(Provider.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider$SystemProviderSingletonHolder.getInstance(FFIProvider.java:68)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider$SystemProviderSingletonHolder.<clinit>(FFIProvider.java:57)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider.getSystemProvider(FFIProvider.java:35)
    at jnr.ffi.Runtime$SingletonHolder.<clinit>(Runtime.java:82)
    at jnr.ffi.Runtime.getSystemRuntime(Runtime.java:67)
    at jnr.unixsocket.SockAddrUnix.<init>(SockAddrUnix.java:46)
    at jnr.unixsocket.SockAddrUnix$DefaultSockAddrUnix.<init>(SockAddrUnix.java:208)
    at jnr.unixsocket.SockAddrUnix.create(SockAddrUnix.java:174)
    at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketAddress.<init>(UnixSocketAddress.java:53)
    at com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder$1.call(NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder.java:261)
    at com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder$1.call(NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder.java:259)
    at com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder.staticAddressResolution(NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder.java:283)
    at 
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:38)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:75)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceOperatorStreamTask$AsyncDataOutputToOutput.emitRecord(SourceOperatorStreamTask.java:309)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.source.SourceOutputWithWatermarks.collect(SourceOutputWithWatermarks.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter$SourceOutputWrapper.collect(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema.deserialize(DeserializationSchema.java:84)
org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.deserializer.KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.deserialize(KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.java:51)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter.emitRecord(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:53)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter.emitRecord(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:33)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.SourceReaderBase.pollNext(SourceReaderBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.SourceOperator.emitNext(SourceOperator.java:419)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskSourceInput.emitNext(StreamTaskSourceInput.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:65)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:562)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:858)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:807)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:953)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:932)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:746)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:562)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.endBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.size(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferFrom(Unknown Source)
    at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.loadFromJar(StubLoader.java:392)
    ... 74 more

    at com.kenai.jffi.Type$Builtin.lookupTypeInfo(Type.java:253)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Type$Builtin.getTypeInfo(Type.java:237)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Type.resolveSize(Type.java:155)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Type.size(Type.java:138)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime$TypeDelegate.size(NativeRuntime.java:178)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.AbstractRuntime.<init>(AbstractRuntime.java:48)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.<init>(NativeRuntime.java:57)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.<init>(NativeRuntime.java:41)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime$SingletonHolder.<clinit>(NativeRuntime.java:53)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.getInstance(NativeRuntime.java:49)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.Provider.<init>(Provider.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider$SystemProviderSingletonHolder.getInstance(FFIProvider.java:68)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider$SystemProviderSingletonHolder.<clinit>(FFIProvider.java:57)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider.getSystemProvider(FFIProvider.java:35)
    at jnr.ffi.Runtime$SingletonHolder.<clinit>(Runtime.java:82)
    at jnr.ffi.Runtime.getSystemRuntime(Runtime.java:67)
    at jnr.unixsocket.SockAddrUnix.<init>(SockAddrUnix.java:46)
    at jnr.unixsocket.SockAddrUnix$DefaultSockAddrUnix.<init>(SockAddrUnix.java:208)
    ... 43 more

We have already tried upgrading to latest 4.4.3 but no luck.
StatsD initiation
  @transient lazy val (statsdO: StatsDClient, appStatsPrefix: String) = setup()

private def setup(): (StatsDClient, String) = {


    statsDConf match {

      case Success(cfg) =>
        val errorHandler = new StatsDClientErrorHandler {
          override def handle(e: Exception): Unit =
            e match {
              case ioe: IOException =>
                log.error("Issue with statsD connection", ioe)
              case _ =>
                log.error("Unknown error with statsD", e)
            }
        }

        val statsd = new NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder()
          .hostname(host)
          .port(port)
          .queueSize(size)
          .constantTags(sometags)
          .errorHandler(errorHandler)
          .originDetectionEnabled(false)
          .enableAggregation(true)
          .build()

        log.info(s"StatsD initialised ${cfg}")
        (statsd, if (cfg.prefix.nonEmpty) cfg.prefix + "." else "")

      case Failure(err) =>
        log.error("Error initialising statsd", err)
        (new NoOpStatsDClient(), "")
    }
  }

Thanks for any help
Checked with java-dogstatsd-client
https://github.com/DataDog/java-dogstatsd-client/issues/258
Tried wrapping statsd init inside try catch to ensure recovery from exception
Verified if the statsD init is replaced with NoOpsClient then the error is fixed.
